# Cannot reposition ImageView in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an ImageView, say imageViewA, in a UICollectionViewCell, say ComicStripViewCellA.xib.  I need to reposition imageViewA if a condition is true.  I can access imageViewA or change its alpha value in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath, but cannot reposition it if this is the first time that this viewCell is dequeued.

But if this viewCell is already in the pool, I can reposition it the next time when collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath is executed.

```
-(UICollectionView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     id <ComicStripViewCell> viewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"comicStripCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (condition) {
          viewCell.imageViewA.alpha = 0.5;  // Always work.
          [viewCell reposition:YES];  // Only work if viewCell is already in the pool.
     }

     return (UICollectionView *)viewCell;
}
```

The following routine is in ComicStripViewCellA.m:

```
-(void)reposition:(BOOL)flag
{
     if (flag) {
          CGPoint center = _imageViewA.center;
          center.x -= 60;
          _imageViewA.center = center;
     }
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the view cell initialization not complete when the reposition routine is run, but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: what is the condition here?

Comment: Try calling [viewCell setNeedsLayout] after [viewCell reposition:YES] call.

Comment: The condition is FBSession.activeSession.isOpen.  I do not believe it has anything to do with the condition though.

Comment: I called [(UICollectionViewCell *)viewCell setNeedsLayout], but still not working.

Comment: registering nib or class for the collectionViewCell??

Comment: Yes, it is properly registered.  The view cell is displayed fine with the appropriate contents.  My only problem is I cannot reposition the image view in viewCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting around, it would appear that the UICollectionViewCell outlets can't be repositioned programmatically (or at least I couldn't get them to reposition, no matter what). One possible solution, however, is to have a simple UIView as the only outlet, and to add subviews to that outlet programmatically, in your case the UIImageView. Once you do that, you can freely reposition any subview in your UIView outlet. I hope this helps!

Comment: viewCell is not null.  I can always access the properties of the viewCell after the dequeue. "ComicStripViewCell" is a @protocol.  It does not require init.  By the way, dequeue will not return nil.  It will create the view cell if it does not exist in the reuse queue.

Comment: Oh yea, you're totally right, then the problem must be that when you get the view, it is not actually already on screen, so changing the center property won't have any effect. Try to NSLog center.x and center.y, i bet it's going to be 0 and 0!

Comment: I added NSLog(@"center = %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(center)) and it does have value {224.5, 12}.  So, the elements of the view cell are initiated fine.

Comment: Wait what center did you log? the viewCell's or the imageView's?

Comment: Please refer to my code under function reposition.  I am logging imageViewA's center.